# How can I change a table entry in q - kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table like:

```
date       sym            time         timeExch     price  volume   new_badTick
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013.05.13 A2A.IM.Equity  08:00:56.000 07:00:56.000 0.6285 124237   0          
2013.05.13 A2A.IM.Equity  08:00:56.000 07:00:56.000 0.6275 10000    0          

q)meta testTab
c          | t f a
-----------| -----
date       | d    
sym        | s    
time       | t    
timeExch   | t    
price      | f    
volume     | j    
new_badTick| i
```

I want to change one single entry, like

```
(first raw, last column):testTab[0][`new_badTick]
```

that is currently `0i`.

But if I try to re-assing it I get an error:

```
q)testTab[0][`new_badTick]:7
'assign
```

Why? How can I change a table entry?

Thanks
Marco

Answer (score 1):

```
testTab[0;`new_badTick]:7
```

or

```
update new_badTick:7 from `testTab where i=0
```

Comment: So just a matter of parenthesis.. Thanks a lot!